# CRM 2016 (2015) Quick Add Menu does not refresh

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've been trying to add more items to Quick Add menu (plus sign in toolbar in 2016 version).

I started in 2015, then patched to 0.1 then upgraded to 2016 and upgraded to SP1 - same deal.

So first I've been trying to add Product quick add form - it's marked as "Allow Quick Add" in the entity properties and it's locked. Still does not show in the Quick Add. I went ahead and checked this check box for Invoice entity - still does not change.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to Quick Create forms.  The entity has to be enabled for QC by checking the "Allow quick create" box on the entity.  Then you have to create a new form of type Quick Create for it, save, and publish.  Refresh CRM and your entity should appear in the Quick Create menu.

Related notes:

- I just tried it for Products and it didn't show up in the menu.  I'm guessing this is because products are supposed to be managed from the Product Catalog page.
- I tried it for Invoice and it worked.
- Native activity entities appear in the QC menu but open the full form instead of using the QC forms (even though you're allowed to create QC forms for them).
- You can enable custom activity entities to support QC forms, and you can create QC forms for those entities. However, the quick create form for custom activity entities will not be used when people click the Create button on the nav bar. These QC forms can be used only when people add a new record for a subgrid that displays that specific custom activity entity.

Comment: I saw multiple walkthroughs where Product shows up in the Quick Add menu...I've been able to finally add custom entity to the menu....but Product was the goal....I guess it's too custom.